# Local minimums and maximums of function of three variables

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

I got such function:
$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 x_2 x_3(4-x_1-x_2-x_3)$
I need to find all local minimums and maximums of this function.
I calculated partial derivatives and I got that the only points where extremums of this function can be located are:
$(1,1,1)$, $(0,0,a)$, $(0, a, 0)$, $(a, 0, 0)$, where $a$ is real.
I don't know how to deal with this $a$, when calculating this matrix for determining if an extremum is a minimum/maximum.
How to deal with it? Can someone show please?

Answer (score 1):

So the function is
$$
f(x,y,z) = 4xyz - x^2yz - xy^2z - xyz^2
$$
so
$$
\nabla f
 = \begin{pmatrix}
4yz - 2xyz - y^2z - yz^2\\
4xz - 2xyz - x^2z - xz^2\\
4xy - 2xyz - xy^2 - x^2y
\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}
yz(4 - 2x - y - z)\\
xz(4 - 2y - x - z)\\
xy(4 - 2z - y - x)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and we must solve $\nabla f = \vec{0}$. The first equation yields 3 cases:

**Case I** $x \ne 0, y \ne 0, z \ne 0$

Then,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2x + y + z = 4\\
2y + x + z = 4\\
2z + y + x = 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so $x=y=z=1$.

**Case II** $y=0$

The only meaningful equation is then the second one, which reduces to $xz(4-x-z)=0$. So we get $(0,0,a), (a,0,0), (4-a,0,a)$ for any real $a$.

All other symmetric cases to the ones we dealt with (which have zeros for one or more of the variables), so you get (1,1,1) and 6 families of solutions: $(a,0,0), (0,a,0), (0,0,a), (4-a,0,a), (0,4-a,a), (a,4-a,0)$.

Plug these back into $f$ to get 0 for all of them except $f(1,1,1)=1$. To classify these, as real minima or saddle points, you can use the 2nd derivative tests. So you possibly have an uncountable infinity of minima which all result in 0 value, and one maximum with value of 1.

Note that the absolute minimum of this surface occurs as $-\infty$, so the minima candidates are only local, not absolute.

Comment: We have $f(t,t,1)=t^2(3-2t)$, so $(1,1,1)$ is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum. Nor is $(0,0,1)$. So I am not clear that you have found any local maxima or minima!

Comment: @almagest actually for your case, $g(t) = 3t^2-2t^3$ so $g'(t) = 6t-6t^2$ with roots precisely at $t=0,1$...

Comment: You are right about $(1,1,1)$. I have been looking more carefully at surface plots around it. But for $(0,0,1)$ we have $f(t,-t,1)=-3t^2$ which is less than $0$ for small $t$. Whereas $f(t,t,1)=3t^2-2t^3>0$ for small $t$.

Comment: @almagest the absolute minimum of this surface is clearly at $-\infty$, so finding a point with negative values does not contradict it being a *local* minimum... it could indeed be possible that specifically at $(0,0,a)$ for $a=1$ it is a saddle point -- feel free to check the conditions...

Comment: Or it could be that it has no local minima. But since you state that it has an uncountable infinity of local minima, you might want to justify the statement. The question specifically asks for local maxima and minima not for local stationary values.

Comment: @almagest left it to the reader instead. thanks for your research

Comment: I need to examine local minimas/maximas. So just checking the value of $f$ at those points isn't sufficient?

Comment: @piternet no, they may end up saddle points.